# How to recursively make sums for a column, grouped by another column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got a table like this.

```
 name | apples | class |
 bob  | 3      |    1  |
 bill | 7      |    1  |
 jack | 6      |    3  |
alice | 1      |    3  |
```

I need to sum the values for each class. How do I get an output as a select query like this in pure sqlite3?

```
 class | apples 
   1   |   10 
   3   |    7
```

I know it should be done by RCTE but can not make a good query for that. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing recursive about this.  It is just simple aggregation:

```
select class, sum(apples)
from t
group by class;
```

The phrasing of your question suggests that you don't know SQL but know procedural programming languages.  SQL is quite different; it is not procedural, it is descriptive:  a SQL query *describes* the results, rather than explaining how they are produced.

Comment: Yep, that was pretty stupid question. Thanks bro, I'm just not familiar with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below - use `sum()` aggregation and `group by`

```
select class,sum(apples) from
tablename
group by class
```